# How To Pass PHP Array to HTML Page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to take some values from a PHP array to a HTML page by clicking a button into a paragraph (`<p>`)

How can I do that?

```
<?php //file called 2.2.php
$numbers = array(1, 8, 11, 26);
echo json_encode($numbers);
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "2.2.php",
                data: "data",
                success:function(data){
                    //WHAT TO WRITE HERE?                   
                },error:function(data){
                alert("bla");                       
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First ``console.log(data);`` check the format of the data, based on that you can manipulate data. Generally you will need ``JSON.parse(data)`` to get into an array format.

Comment: what you actually need? please tell me clear -->your all code are right

Comment: @ParasRaiyani 
i have an array in php numbers(1,8,11,26)
i want to output it in HTML page using AJAX (clicking button)

Comment: //WHAT TO WRITE HERE?  change to console.log(data); and look chrome in console data is display or not

Comment: @ParasRaiyani thanks, man. everything works good. actually i added new stuff below

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data from PHP (which will be text) to JSON, using:

```
JSON.parse( data )
```

Answer (score 0):

THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWERS. BUT I DID IT!
HERE IS FULL CODE:

php part:

```
<?php
if($_POST['data']){
    $numbers = array(1, 8, 11, 26);
    $arr =  json_encode($numbers);
    exit($arr);
}
?>
```

and script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "2.2.php",
                data: "data=1",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#here").html(data);                      
                },error:function(data){
                alert("not working");                       
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and html paragraph and button:

```
<body>
<button id="button">CLICK ME</button>
<p id="here"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: In `success: function (data)` try to `console.log(data)` and see the output to check whether you are getting result or not.

Comment: i have execute your code but it's  properly work,so what's you getting error?please put here your error